# File creation won't take place from within a function in a sourced file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, php, bash-functions

In Ubuntu 16.04 xenial with Bash 4.3.48 and [LEMP](https://lemp.io/), I've created a **comfortability function** to create a [php info file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) (to better know my php environment), and then delete it after 2 hours. but I'm having a problem calling that function from terminal.

### Steps to reproduce my problem

**1)** Create a file with a function:

```
#!/bin/bash
drt="/var/www/html"

pif() {
    cat > "$drt"/info.php <<< "<?php phpinfo();"
    rm "$drt"/info.php | at now + 2 hours
}
```

**2)** Source that file.

**3)** Call the function in terminal:

```
pif
```

Sadly, no file by the name `info.php` was created for me in `/var/www/html`. I double checked that.

<sub>Here's the full trace for executing the function this way (`pif`):</sub>

```
+ pif
+ cat
+ at now + 2 hours
+ rm /var/www/html/info.php
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 17 at Fri Apr  6 05:43:00 2018
```

---

On the other hand, when I try to create the file not from a function, just by executing:

```
cat > "$drt"/info.php <<< "<?php phpinfo();"
```

The file is created fine.

### My question

Why did direct execution from terminal worked but execution of a function containing the code failed?

---

### Update

**1)** I do indeed have write permissions to `/var/www/html`.

**2)** I sourced the file by:

```
source myFunctions.sh
```

**3)** The output of `type -a pif` is:

```
pif is a function
pif ()
{
    cat > "$drt"/info.php <<< "<?php phpinfo();";
    rm "$drt"/info.php | at now + 2 hours
}
```

Comment: @StephenKitt `echo $drt` outputs `/var/www/html`.

Comment: Looks like you're just missing `echo` in front of `rm`.

Comment: @Kusalananda while you wrote this comment I just finished writing an answer about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your function creates `info.php` but then immediately deletes it.

After creating the file `info.php`, it seems like you intend for the next command to *schedule* its deletion:

```
rm "$drt"/info.php | at now + 2 hours
```

But that's not what is happening. That *runs* the `rm` command right now, then [pipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) its [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_output#Standard_output_(stdout)) (to which nothing would typically be written, as `rm` succeeds silently by default) to the `at` command's [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_output#Standard_input_(stdin)).

If you really need to have that shell function schedule the file's deletion, then you should provide the command as text on `at`'s standard input, or schedule a command that runs a separate script that deletes the file. See [at(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/at.1.html) for details about how to schedule commands to run with `at`.

Note that you can actually see, from your trace, that this is what was happening:

```
+ at now + 2 hours
+ rm /var/www/html/info.php
```

Commands in a pipeline run asynchronously. That trace showed that the shell behaved as it should when you give it two commands separated by `|`. It ran the `at` command that appeared on the right side of the pipe so that it could receive data piped from the `rm` command. Then it immediately ran the `rm` command. When it did so, the `rm` command removed the file. To prevent this, you must tell `at` to run that command later, *not* run it immediately in a pipeline yourself.

If you want to use something that resembles what you have, and provided that the value of `drt` (which is `/var/www/html` in your example) does not contain any spaces or other characters that will be treated specially by `/bin/sh` (which `at` uses to run the command), then you can use:

```
at now + 2 hours <<<"rm -- $drt/info.php"
```

If the value of `drt` is known not to start with a `-`, then the `--` argument may be safely omitted. In your situation, where you appear to be in control of `$drt`, this seems like a pretty safe bet.

You may find it convenient to test out your `at` commands by scheduling them to run at some sooner time, such as immediately (`at now`) or in a minute (`at now + 1 minute`).

Comment: @user9303970 It seems to me that there might be a simpler way than `at`, but I'm not totally sure about your requirements. For example, perhaps you could avoid scheduling the deletion of the file, and instead just delete it when you no longer need it. I'm not asserting that this would be suitable for your specific needs, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted Eliah's answer above and I think it should be thumbed up, but here is the explanation I created to myself, regarding a bit different code I particularly used.

### Why the above code was wrong:

It seems that my command failed due to lack of `echo`.

Consider my original command:

```
rm "$drt"/info.php | at now + 2 hours
```

What happened is that the `rm` ran directly after creating the file, **and only then**, an empty `at` ran.

In an even simpler diagram:

> **1)** Create a phpinfo with an here-string.
>
> **2)** Delete phpinfo with `rm` (nothing is further piped anywhere).
>
> **3)** Wait 2 hours (for nothing, in this case).

---

### A correct code

What I should have done (and that works fine and I've double checked that), is this:

```
echo "rm $drt/info.php" | at now + 2 hours
```

The diagram for this command is this:

> **1)** Create a phpinfo with an here-string.
>
> **2)** Echo an `rm` command but pipe the output of the `echo` into the following (`at`) command.
>
> **3)** `rm`at now + 2 hours.

### Conclusion

When using code similar to mine, ensure to wrap the command you want to schedule with `at` with `echo ""`, if you work in the paradigm of `do X at now + y time (from now)`, per the code example above.

Comment: Note that it's not *always* trivial to wrap the command. `echo "rm $drt/info.php" | at now + 2 hours` and `at now + 2 hours <<<"rm $drt/info.php"` work the same and have the same limitations. (I assume you run them from bash, where both are reasonable; bash has `<<<` here-string syntax, and bash's `echo` builtin doesn't expand backslash escapes.) If `$drt` is `/a/b c`, `at` runs `rm /a/b c/info.php`, which would try to delete `/a/b` and separately `c/info.php`. The `"` `"` around the command used with `echo` or `<<<` are not preserved (and if they were, it would not always work as you wanted).